# Textbooks in differential geometry that treat $C^k$ manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, textbook-recommendation

I am looking for textbooks in differential geometry that treat $C^k$ manifolds right from the start. Ideally, the textbook should maintain this general point of view through all chapters and generalize the standard results that can be found for smooth manifolds in all monographs to the case of $C^k$ manifolds.

EDIT: Thank you for the comments so far. My intention with the book is to have a ready reference for research articles. My application is analysis on manifolds.

Comment: To my knowledge no such book exists. If $k\ge 3$ most results should extend more or less trivially even though keeping track of $k$ every time we differentiate is annoying. For smaller $k$, e.g. when $k=1$, things become much more delicate. In general, $C^k$ is probably not the right category. There are several relaxations of $C^\infty$ that are better, notably, Sobolev and Holder.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: can you explain (or give an article) in how far Sobolev and Hölder are better? I am really curious about that.

Comment: it would be easier to find references if you say what you are trying to do in geometry. For example, take a look at the (easily googlable) article "Existence and Regularity of Isometries" Michael Taylor, Transactions AMS, 2006, pp. 2415-2423.

Comment: There's Lang's somewhat idiosyncratic book *Differential and Riemannian Manifolds* (an expanded version of his earlier book *Differential Manifolds*). I suspect that most card-carrying geometers would regard it as sorely lacking in the geometric content (having more focus on foundational formalism, though quite slick for certain purposes).  So it may or may not be what you want, depending on what you have in mind for what should be done in a "textbook in differential geometry".

Comment: Lang does keep track of $k$ to some extent. That's a good reference.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is keep track of differentiability, it's easy enough reading through a book that assumes everything is $C^\infty$ and then check how the theorem would apply assuming lower-orders of differentiability.   I think most authors would consider this an unnecessary distraction and avoid it.  If you are interested in peculiarities due to lack of differentiability, likely you want a much more flexible class of objects.  It all depends on your goals.

Comment: I would say that $C^3$ is enough for 99% of what's done in differential geometry. With some care, $C^2$ is probability enough for 95%, especially Riemannian geometry.. Less than $C^2$ is almost always very hard. If you're not looking for optimal results, it is indeed usually easy to read through a proof and see how many derivatives are needed for each step.